# 2 Errors when trying to build Visual Studio program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm on the last part of my c# program in Visual Studio Community 2015, but I've run into an issue.

I'm using this code to set a cache limit:

```html
private void DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(string folderPath,
                                             long folderSizeLimit,
                                             long amountToDelete)
{
    var folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    var files = folder.GetFiles();
    var folderSize = files.Sum(fi => fi.Length);
 
    if (folderSize > folderSizeLimit)
    {
        // Sort the list of files with the oldest first.
        Array.Sort(files,
                   (fi1, fi2) => fi1.CreationTime.CompareTo(fi2.CreationTime));
 
        var amountDeleted = 0L;
 
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            amountDeleted += file.Length;
            file.Delete();
 
            if (amountDeleted >= amountToDelete)
            {
                break;
            }
 
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my full code for the class that's causing the errors:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Forge
{
    class Delete
    {
        private void DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(string folderPath,
                                                long folderSizeLimit,
                                                long amountToDelete)
        {
            var folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            var files = folder.GetFiles();
            var folderSize = files.Sum(fi => fi.Length);

            if (folderSize > folderSizeLimit)
            {
                // Sort the list of files with the oldest first.
                Array.Sort(files,
                           (fi1, fi2) => fi1.CreationTime.CompareTo(fi2.CreationTime));

                var amountDeleted = 0L;

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    amountDeleted += file.Length;
                    file.Delete();

                    if (amountDeleted >= amountToDelete)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I need to insert any info. for my specific program, though (i.e. folder path, size limit, etc.) This might be the problem.

Anyways, I learned I needed to add this code to a class so I went to "Program>Add Class" to make a class. I then added the code. But when I go to build the program these two errors pop up:

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'DirectoryInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) *- Line 15*
>
> Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' *- Line 27*

Can anybody help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

(PS Sorry, I'm ***super*** new to this whole coding thing.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] *in the question*. We shouldn't have to follow links to see the broken code. My guess is that you don't have a `using` directive for `System.IO`.

Comment: You're missing `using System.IO;` at the top of your program which is the namespace containing `DirectoryInfo`. For the second issue show me the line that throws the error, I don't want to read your entire project.

Comment: Second heavily DV'd post - it is never too late to read [Ask] and take the [Tour] since you are new to this whole question asking thing

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I really have no idea what I'm doing and it's always so helpful when people politely point me toward what I should learn or do.

Comment: Equalsk (Sorry, I don't know how to "tag" people yet.
Adding `using System.IO;` seemed to get rid of both errors.

Comment: Do any of you possibly know where to insert the data for the cache limit?

Here's my original question on another forum:
**I want to set a cache limit for my c# program. My program is creating files periodically and saving them to a folder. I want it so if the folder (C:\SysApp) hits this limit (150000KB) it will automatically start deleting the files starting with the oldest ones deleting only a certain amount at a time (149900KB).**

Comment: Never mind about the tagging, I figured it out. I for some reason missed the whole last half of how to comment. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have the fix, adding the assembly dependency with:

```
using System.IO
```

But I would like to point out that the use of the anonymous type "var" is going to cause more issue than anything. If you know what the type is, declare it. This not only makes your code more verbose but also will circumvent issue with missing dependencies (the editor will tell you rather than the compiler).

Here is your code refactored:

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
FileInfo[] files = folder.GetFiles();
long folderSize = files.Sum(fi => fi.Length);

if (folderSize > folderSizeLimit)
{
    // Sort the list of files with the oldest first.
    Array.Sort(files,
               (fi1, fi2) => fi1.CreationTime.CompareTo(fi2.CreationTime));

    long amountDeleted = 0L;

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        amountDeleted += file.Length;
        file.Delete();

        if (amountDeleted >= amountToDelete)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That'll really help in the long run. :)

Do you possibly know where to insert the data for the cache limit?
**Here's my original question on another forum: I want to set a cache limit for my c# program. My program is creating files periodically and saving them to a folder. I want it so if the folder (C:\SysApp) hits this limit (150000KB) it will automatically start deleting the files starting with the oldest ones deleting only a certain amount at a time (149900KB).**

Comment: @ReiSIxx9 you should create another post on this site. No one will answer as sub question in comments :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea why any time I ask a question and it gets 2 votes down for some reason that I can't post a question for another week afterwards? Or maybe a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

Use this on top of your code

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of both errors and I was able to successfully build it. :)

Comment: @ReiSIxx9 you need to click on the check mark below the large number at the left. If it becomes a green tick mark, then the answer is accepted.

Comment: @rashfmnb I do not understand why your answer has been down-voted, as it clearly resolved the problem of ReiSlxx9. I experienced the same down-voting habit a lot lately without explanation.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad i dont know why people do it